# Sequelize: temporarily disable timestamps

Tags: sequelize.js

Is there a way in Sequelize.js to temporarily disable timestamps, ideally for one single query?

In particular, I'm running a query like

```
MyModel.update({
    UserId: 1
}, {
    where: {
        UserId: 2
    }
}).then(...)
```

and I don't want the timestamps to update. I do want them to update for any other queries which are going on unrelated to this context.

I've tried setting `MyModel.options.timestamps = false` before running the `update()` and setting it back to `true` right after, and I've also, just to experiment, tried *not* setting it back to `true` again. The timestamp still gets updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `silent` option for `MyModel.update()`.

From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-save):

> `[options.silent=false]   Boolean     If true, the updatedAt timestamp will not be updated.`

Comment: This same option works on at least some other operations. It works on `create`, for example. Without it, the `createdAt` can be set manually but the `updatedAt` will be overridden by the current time. With it, both can be set manually.